# Is the term "byte" useless now?

Tags: terminology

As all of us probably know, a byte is 8 bits that can store 256 different binary numbers. This term feels like it can only be used for 8-bit computers that actually use bits in groups of 8. But most computers today aren't 8-bit. Most are 64-bit today, and a single 64-bit word is 8 bytes. I think that RAMs and other memory storage compartments should be measured by the number of words instead of an arbitrary 8-bit value. Lets take a 8GB 64-bit RAM. That would be one billion words. But a 4GB 32-bit RAM is also one billion words, so words are more important than bytes. So why do we still use bytes, and should we ditch the whole term?

Comment: Most computers are NOT 64-bit. I don't think most are even 32-bit. The computer in your thermostat or oven is not 64-bits and does not have gigabytes of RAM.

Comment: Many serial protocols use 8-bit transmission.

Comment: Even if a system is capable of working with 64 bit words, the software may pack two 32 bit values into it (or 4 16 bit values, or 8 8 bit values). A lot of addressing can done at the byte level, not word.

Comment: "words are more important than bytes" Sorry, no, this is just wrong.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because english

Comment: Most of the internet protocols are specified in terms of "octets"...

Comment: I think this a wonderful idea. Then we could get rid of those horrible 'kibibyte', 'mebibyte', and 'gibibyte' units that people insist we must use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> This term feels like it can only be used for 8-bit computers that actually use bits in groups of 8. But most computers today aren't 8-bit. Most are 64-bit today, and a single 64-bit word is 8 bytes.

The fundamental unit of memory access on most computer systems, 32 and 64 bit computers included, is the byte and not the word.  Hence, we use bytes for describing the capacity of memory, since that is what is actually used.

> I think that RAMs and other memory storage compartments should be measured by the number of words instead of an arbitrary 8-bit value.

This would be a bad idea because:

1.8-bit is not arbitrary, it is the actual size with which almost all architectures address DRAM.  Using a unit for memory size that did not match the unit used for addressing memory would be ambiguous and extremely confusing (see below).

2.The word size on systems varies widely, meaning that defining the size of a memory would require knowing what you were going to plug into.

Usually you only see memory specified in units of words when it is internal to the system and/or not byte addressable since then 1 and 2 do not apply.

> Lets take a 8GB 64-bit RAM. That would be one billion words.

To illustrate how confusing that would be, consider that on x86 a "word" is defined as 16 bits and that a "64-bit RAM" is typically made from 4-8 smaller 8/16 bit DRAMs, while different PC processors use different fundamental memory bus widths. 1 billion words could be 1 billion bytes, 2 billion bytes or 8 billion bytes depending on how you define the word in that context.

Answer (score 2):

That would be **A LOT** more confusing than bytes. Additionally, byte is still the most used unit in most of the computer world, so much of the existing architecture is based on or centered around the byte size, it has been working very well so far and it continues to work, so there is hardly a reason to abandon it. Whether it "feels" like it's an "old ancient measure used for ancient technologies" it is still the most appropriate and easiest to use and understand.
The vast majority of people would never understand what they got if the storage and file sizes were shown in *words* whose definition is not strictly a single number as in bytes, but dependent upon or referenced to the system used.
 People want it simple, and one specific unit of measure of one specific size. Constants are a lot easier to understand and work with than variables.

Comment: this is all right, but the important part really is that memory access is byte-granular on basically any general-purpose computer architecture, no matter what the word length is.

Answer (score 2):

The number of *bytes* in memory is a pretty good measure of the amount of complexity that computer can handle at a given time without bogging down.

And all general-purpose processors these days can address memory as bytes -- and do so when dealing with text or other "blobs" of information.  So your 64-bit ARM, Intel or AMD processor *can* read data 64 bits at a time (and go faster because of it), but it can also read and process data 8 bits at a time.

There are a very few machines out there whose minimum word size is larger than 8 bits -- these days its limited to DSP chips which are designed to do almost no text or other general-purpose tasks, but are fast at number crunching.  In the past there have been supercomputers (i.e. the Crays) that had 64-bit word lengths, and would store one character per 64 bits -- but those are obsolete now; if you want a supercomputer today you end up with lots and lots of desktop processors in a server rack.

By and large, a 64-bit computer and a 32-bit computer that are solving the same problem (say, keeping you happy while playing Dwarf Fortress and chatting online with friends) are going to use roughly the same amount of memory.  The 64-bit computer may use a bit more because it'll be a bit less efficient with storage, but it won't use *much* more.

The big difference between an 8-, 16-, etc., bit machine is how much memory it can easily address, and how fast it does its computation.  A 64-bit processor with 32kB of memory* really can't solve a more complex problem than an 8-bit processor with 32kB of memory -- but it can probably do it a lot faster.

* Yes, this is an absurd example.

Comment: Not that absurd an example – during early boot, x86_64 hasn't got any access to the actual RAM, but works from small internal caches.

Comment: @MarcusMüller are they truly as small as 32kB?  I hadn't thought of it, but I guess it's obvious that until the DRAM is properly initialized memory will be tight.

Comment: Well, I must admit I haven't booted an x86_64 myself, but since the i386, all these CPUs boot in real mode – where the visible memory is 16 kB at a time! (you can, however, select a segment out of 1 MB in total -- woohoo!)